# PySide code convention and naming

Tags: python, pyside

Is exists any docs where I can find strict rules for naming in python code which use PySide?

If not which I *should* use camelCase or unde_score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to follow [pep8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions), the Python style guide. However, "New modules and packages (including third party frameworks) should be written to these standards, but where an existing library has a different style, internal consistency is preferred." Python generally uses CamelCase for classes, and seperation_by_underscores for everything else.